# Connections not obeying conntrack

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat, conntrack

I have a tunnel set up on interface vti68. I am NATing both the source and destination.

- The host has 10.1.30.51 as local, and 172.16.0.80 as remote.
- Traffic in the tunnel is translated such that 10.45.89.4 is local and 192.168.7.5 is remote.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x44 lookup table68
ip route add table table68 default dev vti68

sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vti68.rp_filter=0

# use table68 for routing
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.56 -j MARK --set-mark 0x44

# NAT
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.56 -j CT --zone 68
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.56 -j DNAT --to 192.168.7.5
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i vti68 -d 10.45.89.4 -j CT --zone 68
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vti68 -s 10.1.30.51 -j SNAT --to 10.45.89.4

# not necessary for example, but the reverse translation, for completeness
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -i vti68 -s 192.168.7.5 -j SNAT --to 172.16.0.56
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vti68 -d 10.45.89.4 -j DNAT --to 10.1.30.51\

# debug
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j LOG  --log-level=1
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j LOG --log-level=1
```

Pinging the remote server hangs

```
ping -c1 172.16.0.56
```

But using iptables log, I see the packet returning. (Oddly, the SRC of the reply have not been reversed translated by conntrack, but as far as I can tell that is normal).

```
kernel: IN= OUT=vti68 SRC=10.1.30.51 DST=172.16.0.56 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=13082 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=26071 SEQ=1 
kernel: IN=vti68 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.7.5 DST=10.1.30.51 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=126 ID=26747 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=26071 SEQ=1
```

and tcpdump shows the repy

```
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 126, id 26794, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.7.5 > 10.45.89.4: ICMP echo reply, id 26071, seq 1, length 64
```

And `conntrack -E` shows the reply

```
    [NEW] icmp     1 30 src=10.1.30.51 dst=172.16.0.56 type=8 code=0 id=26071 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.7.5 dst=10.45.89.4 type=0 code=0 id=26071 zone=68
 [UPDATE] icmp     1 29 src=10.1.30.51 dst=172.16.0.56 type=8 code=0 id=26071 src=192.168.7.5 dst=10.45.89.4 type=0 code=0 id=26071 zone=68
```

TCP connections are similar:

```
    [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=10.1.30.51 dst=172.16.0.56 sport=54336 dport=3389 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.7.5 dst=10.45.89.4 sport=3389 dport=54336 zone=68
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.1.30.51 dst=172.16.0.56 sport=54336 dport=3389 src=192.168.7.5 dst=10.45.89.4 sport=3389 dport=54336 zone=68
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.1.30.51 dst=172.16.0.56 sport=54336 dport=3389 src=192.168.7.5 dst=10.45.89.4 sport=3389 dport=54336 zone=68
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.1.30.51 dst=172.16.0.56 sport=54336 dport=3389 src=192.168.7.5 dst=10.45.89.4 sport=3389 dport=54336 zone=68
```

---

More strangely, I have done all these steps for a different interface and addresses and remote host, and everything appears identical, except that ICMP relies and TCP connections actually complete.

---

Why would the connections show up in conntrack as replying, but the program does not receive it? What more could I look at?